# I'm trying to install ubuntu replacing with my windows7, and I got this error

Tags: live-usb

I'm trying to install ubuntu replacing with my windows7, and I got this error

```
(hd0,0)
Filesystem type is iso9960_Joliet, using whole disk
kernel /casper/vmlinuz file=/pressed/ubuntu.seed noprompt boot=casper iso-scan/filename=%ISO% quiet --

Error 13:(http://grub4dos.chemall.net/e/13)
         Invalid or unsupported executable format

Press any key to continue...
```

I search so many solution for this yet it doesn't help at all.

Comment: What did you do to get that error ?

Comment: nothing, I'm just creating a bootable drive using (Universal USB installer) to replace my windows7 OS to ubuntu, then while in boot section it gives me already that error.